# how to show image in the column of repeater control in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, html

I'm using repeater control from asp.net for data binding. And for designing i used the div & span for data representation. I have 4 fields to my table & i want to show the images on the each span depending on the field value. Images are stored in my project path itself.

How to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterImages" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <img src='<%#GetImage(Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageID"))%>' alt="" width="" height="" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now we need to create a function to retrieve the image using that ID.

```
public string GetImage(object ImadeID)
        {
          if(ImageID!=null)
            {
               //do something with the ImageID to return the image path as string
            }
          else
           {
           return "";
          }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterImages" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I haven't stored my images in my table. the table is having some integer field value. and depending on that value i want to show the image. then how to do this? I i want to use html <img> for showing image.

Comment: i didnt get your idea ? what are you doing . are you storing 1 and 2 in table and for 1 show true.jpg and for 2 show false.jpg

Comment: i m storing 0 to 4 value to my field. and depending on that value i want to display the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterImages" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Container.DataItem %>' 
Visible ='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() == "0" ? true : false %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```