# Show images in Repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net, asprepeater

I have the following `List`:

```
private List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image> _searchResultList = new List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image>();
```

This List may contain several Images with different URLs.

I have the following `Repeater`:

```
<asp:Panel ID="SearchPanel" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image height="32" width="32" runat="server"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Panel>
```

Using `DataSource` to display the images doesn't seem to work.

```
Repeater.DataSource = _searchResultList;           
Repeater.DataBind();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33597934/select-all-images-using-asp-net-c-sharp

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885444/how-to-show-image-in-the-column-of-repeater-control-in-asp-net ?

Comment: Do you have these images serialized in files somewhere on the server side? The way you display images on a web page is that you have them as files, and you reference them on the web page by providing source information to Image tags. There is no easy way to render just an Image object

Comment: @Andrei The standard path to the images is "~/Images/ORAS/". If I create a normal Image on the aspx page I can add an Image by using ImageUrl, but it doesn't work if I have to create them in code-behind.

Comment: @Kohnarik...The `_searchResultList` is not a list of strings so you can't use `ImageURL='<%Container.DataItem.ToString()%>'`. Because `_searchResultList` is a list of images you should bind the `ImageUrl` property. This should works fine for you: `<ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" height="32" width="32" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>`

Comment: @user2946329 I did that before and it didn't work, but now it does. I have no idea what changed. Nonetheless, thank you so much!

Comment: @user2946329 Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_searchResultList` is not a list of strings so you can't use `ImageURL='<%Container.DataItem.ToString()%>'`. Because `_searchResultList` is a list of images you should bind the `ImageUrl` property. This should works fine for you:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate> 
       <asp:Image ID="Image1" height="32" width="32" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' /> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In this example `Container.DataItem` refers to an `Image` control. This is why we used `Eval("ImageUrl")` to get the `ImageUrl` property of each `Image` control.

Comment: In this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33694399/2946329 that I shown you earlier you could use `ImageURL='<%Container.DataItem.ToString()%>'` because  the source is a List of string. But in this example `Container.DataItem` refers to an `Image` control. This is why we used `Eval("ImageUrl")` to get the `ImageUrl` of each image control.

Comment: I didn't realize that. That's very helpful information. Thank you.

Comment: Ohh I see. Sorry, I'm kind of brain-afk today. I upvoted it

Answer (score 1):

```
        <asp:Panel ID="SearchPanel" runat="server" crollBars="Vertical">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server">
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image height="32" width="32" runat="server" ImageURL='<%Container.DataItem.ToString()%>'/>// changes here
        </ ItemTemplate>
           </asp:Repeater>
            </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: As much as I'd like this to work, it doesn't do anything for me. I've checked the _searchResultList and the Images are all in there, like they should. If I add an asp:Image element outside the Repeater and use the same ImageURL, it works. But inside the Repeater, even if I use a static ImageURL, it doesn't show up.

Comment: Okay, if I change the ImageURL inside the Repeater to ImageURL="~/Images/ORAS/006.png" and there are 17 images in my _searchResultList, the Image 006.png will show up 17 times.

Comment: give me an example of the url in the list

Comment: ~/Images/ORAS/006-mx.png

Comment: hey remove databinder.eval just use <%Container.DataItem.ToString()%> ImageUrl='<%Container.DataItem.ToString()%>

Comment: That doesn't work either. Although it does seem to recognize the correct amount of pictures, it does not show them. If I highlight the whole page, I can see the correct amount of [squares](http://imgur.com/0SXzFTU) where the pictures are supposed to be at. Without selection: [Normal](http://imgur.com/C6tjBK1)

Comment: It means the path is not proper. first try removing the ~ sign before the path, also check if the images are present in the path provided.coz this worked perfectly for me

Comment: right click use inspect elements to check what path the images are getting

Comment: Instead of ~, I used the exact path, but no change. The path is correct. I even tried adding an ImageURL with Visual Studio's "Choose URL" feature. Creating an image outside the Panel & Repeater works like a charm: <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/ORAS/004.png" />

Comment: right click on the images and check what path is coming (Inspect element)

Comment: Images/ORAS/004.png, but removing ~/ before the images to achieve the shown path does not work either.

Comment: Using <asp:Image ID="Image1" height="32" width="32" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' /> resolved the issue. Thank you very much for your patience, help and time!