# Showing images in a repeater control when you have a path plus a filename

Tags: c#, asp.net

My question is very similar to this:

[Show images in Repeater control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721236/show-images-in-repeater-control)

The selected answer to that question is this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" height="32" width="32" runat="server" 
  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' />
```

However, in my case, I have a pre-selected filename path.  I've tried this and it doesn't work:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" height="32" width="32" runat="server" 
  ImageUrl='D:\MyPics\Photos\<%# Eval("PhotoLink") %>' />
```

The Eval doesn't get converted to anything, and when I look at my source after the page is rendered it says:

```
<img src="D:\MyPics\Photos\&lt;%#Eval(&quot;PhotoLink&quot;)%
```

I'm sure it's something really stupid, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use string formatting:

```
ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("D:\MyPics\Photos\{0}", Eval("PhotoLink")) %>'
```

Comment: I had to change the "\" to "/" or it prompted me with an error, but that seemed to work.  The image isn't showing up, but that's probably a different question because the "<img src>" tag is showing up properly.