# images are not displaying from image links on repeater

Tags: sql, asp.net, html-agility-pack, repeater

i have crawled a website using html agility pack and the images links are stored in my SQL database, but when i display those images on my ASP web form on repeater images are showing nothing but a broken mark or cannot see images, is it the links unable to take image online or what is the problem? i have checked all the image links they work fine and show images when i search them on browser but cannot see them in repeater what can be the problem?

```
 <div style="width:100%; height:100%; margin-top:35px;">      
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">

                <ItemTemplate>

                    <div style="border: 2px none #0d0c0c; width:70%; background-color:#37546f; margin-left:70px; border:inset;">
                        <table>
                            <tr style="height:180px; width:180px;">
                                <td style=" width:200px;">

                                    <asp:Image ID="Laptop" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageLink")%>' Height="212px" Width="180px" runat="server" />

                                        </td>

                                <td >
                                    <table style="margin-top:-25px;">
                                        <tr>

                                            <td style="color: black; font-style: italic;  font-size: large;">NAME

                                               </td>

                                            <br />
                                            <br />

                                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <%#Eval("Name") %>

                                     </td>

                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="color: black; font-style: italic; font-size: large;">PRICE
                                                <br />
                                            </td>
                                            <br />

                                            <td>

                                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                <%#Eval("Price") %>

                                            </td>

                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="color: black; font-style: italic; font-size: large;"> Link

                                                <br />

                                            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=" <%#Eval("Link") %> ">For more details..</a>   </td>

                                        </tr>

                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>

     </asp:Repeater>
         </div>
```

Comment: Can you share one of the image links from the DB?

Comment: Try the following link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885444/how-to-show-image-in-the-column-of-repeater-control-in-asp-net

Comment: @Kami http://www.shophive.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/165x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/g/a/gallery1_2256_1_2.jpg

Comment: When you click on the link you sent me you'll see why the images are not displaying.

Comment: @Kami didn't get it can u elaborate please? coz browser is showing image but can't see in repeater

Comment: When I click on the link I go the following error in Google Chrome: The owner of this website (www.shophive.com) does not allow hotlinking to that resource. In firefox I can see the image.

Comment: @Kami but when i search that source on browser the image is being displayed, plus what is the solution for this problem?

Comment: @Kami i can't even see in firefox

Comment: @MarchingGazelle still can't see, broken images are being displayed, don't know what to do

Comment: @ShehrozJalil, I was logged off for the past 12 hours. I haven't had a chance to review it any further. It appears to be more a permissions issue.

Comment: @Kami hmm and the other way is that i will have to download all the images and then use them on my Web form, i was thinking if hot linking is possible my work would be like more than 50% complete, and there is no way to cope with this hot linking problem?

Comment: Nope, unless the site owner allows it.

Comment: No problem. Sorry, I could not help further.